# Why my SAW (Simple Additive Weighting) can't show the result?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, artificial-intelligence

I want to show the result of my SAW code, but when I load this, it just shows "The query you submitted is not valid". Then, if I use `implode` to collect my variable like `$skill` then I have error message like "unifined index skill". please help me.

This is the SAW Code

```
    // collect skill
    $skill = array();
    $sk = $_POST["skill"];
    foreach ($sk as $sek) {
        array_push($skill, "'".$sek."'");
    }
    $skills = implode(",",$skill);

    // collect nilai
    $nilai = $this->input->post("nilai");

    //collect gaji
    $gaji = $this->input->post("gaji");

    // collect Lokasi
    $lokasi = ($this->input->post("lokasi") == "0" ? false : true);

    // collect jurusan
    $jurusan = $this->input->post("jurusan");

    $sql = $this->model_data->getRating($skills, $nilai, $gaji, $lokasi, $jurusan);

    $result = $this->db->query("$sql")->result();

    $saw = new Algoritma();
    // menambahkan Kriteria
    $saw->addCriteria("skill",$this->input->post("bobot_skill")/100,"1");
    $saw->addCriteria("nilai",$this->input->post("bobot_nilai")/100,"0");
    $saw->addCriteria("gaji",$this->input->post("bobot_gaji")/100,"0");
    $saw->addCriteria("lokasi",$this->input->post("bobot_lokasi")/100,"1");
    $saw->addCriteria("jurusan",$this->input->post("bobot_jurusan")/100,"1");


    foreach ($result as $hasil) {
        $alt = new Alternative("$hasil->kode_lowongan","$hasil->nama_perusahaan");
        $alt->addCriteria("skill",$hasil->skill);
        $alt->addCriteria("nilai",$hasil->nilai);
        $alt->addCriteria("gaji",$hasil->gaji);
        $alt->addCriteria("lokasi",$hasil->lokasi);
        $alt->addCriteria("jurusan",$hasil->jurusan);

        $saw->addAlternative($alt);
    }
    $saw->generate();
    $rekomendasi = $saw->data;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($rekomendasi); $i++) {
        for ($j=($i+1); $j < count($rekomendasi); $j++) {
            if($rekomendasi[$i]->preferensi < $rekomendasi[$j]->preferensi){
                $temp = $rekomendasi[$i];
                $rekomendasi[$i] = $rekomendasi[$j];
                $rekomendasi[$j] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }
    $data["hasil"] = $rekomendasi;
    $this->load->view("home/sawhasil",$data);
}
```

I used Codeigniter for code.

Comment: Welcome to SO, There are several things you could check strait away. Probably `var_dump($_POST);` to see what your POST variable actually contains and `var_dump($sql);` to see what your `$sql` variable, which is later used for query  contains. Judging by the error messages these two variable have differnt values than you expect. `getRating()` function would be the second to check - it probably is the source of the `invalid query` - but that is a guess

Comment: You have a closing `}` in the end and no opening one in the beginning, looks like you skipped one line, please restore it. Also please specify how do you *load this*, because if you open it in a browser, it opens it with a GET request and your `$_POST` is expected to be empty.

Comment: This is my function get rating:

`function getRating($skill, $nilai, $gaji, $lokasi, $jurusan ){
    $parameter = array(
      "skill" => $skill,
      "nilai" => $nilai,
      "gaji" => $gaji,
      "lokasi" => $lokasi,
      "jurusan" => $jurusan,  
    );

  $p='';
  for($i=0;$i<count($parameter);$i++){
   if($p=='') $p='?';
   else $p.=',?';
  }
  $proc="call rating($p)";
  $query=$this->db->query($proc,$parameter);
  $sqltext = $query->row()->sqltext;
  // $query->free_result();
  mysqli_next_result( $this->db->conn_id );

  return $sqltext;
  }`